# Расположение элементов в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

Есть у меня класс, описывающий правую панель моего **GUI - приложения с кнопками**:

```
public class RightMenu extends GridPane {

public RightMenu() {

    Button startButton = new Button("Старт");
    Button stopButton = new Button("Стоп");
    Button clearButton = new Button("Очистить график");

    this.add(startButton, 0, 0);
    this.add(stopButton,  1, 0);
    this.add(clearButton,  0, 1);

    this.setPadding(new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2));
}
```

}

**Выглядит это вот так:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы видите кнопки расположены очень криво. Как мне сделать так, чтобы кнопка "Очистить график" была под обоими кнопками "Старт" и "Стоп", то есть, занимала две колонки ? И как вообще грамотно сделать выравнивание кнопок ?

Comment: какой layout вы используете?

Comment: наследуюсь от GridPane

Comment: Ой, не заметил, надо в ячейке задать слияние this.setColumnSpan(Node child, Integer value)

Comment: А что указывать в качестве ребенка и целочисленного значения ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы сделать так, как вы хотите, необходимо вызывать метод

```
GridPane.setColumnSpan(clearButton,2);
```

Этот метод растянет кнопку на 2 колонки. Так же, чтобы она была по центру (горизонтальному), необходимо сделать так

```
GridPane.setHalignment(clearButton, HPos.CENTER);
```

Для вертикального выравнивания, нужно использовать `setValigment`

Comment: Все получилось, но нижняя кнопка clearButton заняла гораздо больше места, чем верхние startButton и stopButton, из-за чего в правом верхнем углу образовалось лишнее пространство. Как избавиться от него ?

Comment: Сделайте GridPane.setHaligment(stopButton, HPos.RIGHT)

Comment: GridPane не знает метода setHaligment...

Comment: GridPane.setHalignment

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант немного лохмат, но как вариант, тоже подходит.
Суть в том что вместо сетки зарядить фокус с Hbox и VBox.
Мы берем и создаем VBox и Hbox

```
VBox vbox = new VBox();
HBox hbox = new HBox();
```

Те кнопки, что должны быть в ряд заряжаем в `hbox`

```
hbox.getChildren().addAll(startButton, stopButton);
```

Так мы получили ряд из двух кнопок, а теперь мы выстраиваем столбец из этого ряда и другой кнопки

```
vbox.getChildren().addAll(hbox, clearButton);
```

**PS** Я все таки надеюсь что есть адекватный способ обединения ячеек в таблице. Но в тот раз я не стал заморачиваться в поисках и просто сделал так. (Благо у меня тоже была маленькая панелька)

Comment: Это не выход, т.к.  размеры разъедутся и получится, что нижняя кнопка намного больше верхних двух уезжает вперед (пробовал). Можно, конечно, подставить пробелы, но это уже совсем костыльные костыли.

Comment: Уезжает вперед? А если подправить размер кнопок или spacing у hbox задать?

Comment: Можно поподробнее ?

Comment: spacing у VBox и HBox - это расстояние между соседними нодами.

Comment: 2faoxis А вобще, я говорил и говорю: Используйте FXML. Там вам и MVC, и визуальный редактор.

Comment: Я не знаю XML, а на его изучение в данный момент нет времени. :(

Comment: А тут учить много и не надо: Взять редактор отсюда http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/ и посмотреть как его загрузить и привязать контроллер http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/ru/ . Это ведь не какой-то другой фреймворк, а часть JavaFX